# Using gsub() to replace all numbers except after certain substrings

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

Say we have:

```
TestStrings <- c("Some number < 100", "Some number > 999", "Some number $1000", "Some number 1000000")
```

I want to replace all numbers with a space except numbers following the substrings:

```
"< \\d+"   "> \\d+"   "$\\d+"
```

What Regular expression could I write in function `gsub()` to complete such a task.

I know the follow code is wrong but here is what I have.

```
gsub(pattern = "^> \\d+|^< \\d+|^$\\d+", replace = " ", TestStrings)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following pattern:

```
[a-z]\s*\K\d+
```

Here's a [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb1gbw/1).

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) it would be:

```
gsub("[a-z]\\s*\\K\\d+", "", TestStrings, perl = T)

 # [1] "Some number < 100"   "Some number > 999"
 # [3] "Some number $1000"   "Some number "
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
gsub("[<>] \\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", " ", TestStrings, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Some number < 100" "Some number > 999" "Some number $ "    "Some number  "
```

If we don't need the `$`

```
gsub("[<>] \\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\$*\\d+", " ", TestStrings, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Some number < 100" "Some number > 999" "Some number  "     "Some number  "
```

If we need the `$` and the numbers

```
gsub("([<>] |\\$)\\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", " ", TestStrings, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Some number < 100" "Some number > 999" "Some number $1000" "Some number  "
```

Comment: This works for everything but the dollar sign. It replaces the dollar sign and the number after. It does help a ton though thank you so much!

Comment: @HunterThomas I used the `$` to remove that.  I didn't have an idea about your expected output

Comment: @HunterThomas Can you check the output now

Comment: Everything there is great in the first one. The only other thing is I also need the number after the dollar sign.

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, I actually figured out something as well. Here is my code.        gsub("[<>] \\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\$\\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", " ", TestString, perl = TRUE)      This also works, but it's a little messy and redundant. I am new to regex so I don't exactly know how the syntax works.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
gsub("[<>\\$] ?\\d+", " ", TestStrings)
```

It returns:

```
[1] "Some number  "       "Some number  "       "Some number  "       "Some number 1000000"
```

which I think is what you are looking for.

**EDIT** Actually you want the opposite, so

```
gsub("([<>\\$] ?\\d+)|\\d+", "\\1", TestStrings)
```

```
[1] "Some number < 100" "Some number > 999" "Some number $1000" "Some number "
```

Comment: What I am looking for is "Some number < 100"      "Some number > 999"    "Some number $1000"    "Some number        "  Sorry for the confusion, you're very helpful